# How do I make a delete BUTTON to remove an item from a list (macOS app)?

Tags: swiftui

I am creating a Notes style app. I want the user to be able to delete a note without having to "swipe to delete". So I do not want to use .onDelete.

I have a trashcan icon next to the note name that I'd like the user to press to delete. I know this can be done in an iOS app using .onTapGesture, but I'm not sure how to do it in a macOS app.

If this can't be done another option would be to create a delete button on the toolbar. Once again, I am not sure how to implement the code to delete the list when the button is pressed.

Here is what I tried in the list view itself:

```
import SwiftUI

struct NoteListView: View {
    let myNotes: [MyNoteViewModel]

    var body: some View {
        List(myNotes) {myNote in
            HStack{
                NoteCellView(noteModel: myNote)
                Image(systemName: "trash")
                // where to potentially implement deletion when trash icon is pressed. 

            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

NoteCellView:

```
struct NoteCellView: View {
    
    let noteModel: MyNoteViewModel
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Image(systemName: "folder")
            Text(noteModel.name)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

MyNoteViewModel:

```
struct MyNoteViewModel: Identifiable{
    private let myNote: MyNote
    
    init(myNote: MyNote){
        self.myNote = myNote
        
    }
    var id: NSManagedObjectID{
        myNote.objectID
    }
    
    var name: String {
       myNote.name ?? ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onTapGesture`on macOS too :).
But the list of notes has to be a @State or @StateObject var, otherwise you can't change (or delete from) it.

Here is a simplified example:

```
struct NoteListView: View {
    
    @State var myNotes = ["note 1", "note 2", "note 3", "another note"]

    var body: some View {
        List(myNotes, id: \.self) { myNote in
            HStack{
                Text(myNote)
                Image(systemName: "trash")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        if let index = myNotes.firstIndex(of: myNote) {
                            withAnimation {
                                myNotes.remove(at: index)
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not letting me convert my list of notes into a State or StateObject. Is there another solution? Here is my list code:                                                                    import Foundation
import CoreData

struct MyNoteViewModel: Identifiable{
    private let myNote: MyNote
    
    init(myNote: MyNote){
        self.myNote = myNote
        
    }
    var id: NSManagedObjectID{
        myNote.objectID
    }
    
    var name: String {
       myNote.name ?? ""
    }
}

Comment: it looks like you're using CoreData to save your notes. IMHO then you don't need a view model. Just fetch the notes in the view with @FetchRequest. And delete using the appropriate core data function.